# PHP shell_execute skipping input while running from commandline - git bash

Tags: php, ssh

I'm running into an issue while executing a PHP(7.4) script through git bash on windows.

The PHP script runs the following code sample:

```
<?php
   shell_exec("git clone git@gitlab.com/the/repository/i/try/to/clone/example.git");
?>
```

While running this code from the git bash command-line (on windows)
it prompts me for my SSH passphrase, but this gets skipped (it never let me give input)
and then fails with the following message.

> git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The error is logical as it expects a password which i wasn't able to provide.

Does anyone have a solution on why it skips user input while running the git command through php?

Comment: This is not due to bash, Git, or any shell at all. It's due to ssh, which wants to read a user's passphrase, and refuses to read it from something that's not—in ssh's opinion at least—talking to a *user*. Automated operations should use automation tokens or ssh keys, not user tokens or ssh keys; these should be readable by the automation system without requiring user input. (How you arrange that is up to you.) I'm not sure that PHP itself is even in the mix here, but I suppose it could be.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, thanks! I'm going to look in to that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @torek, you where right that definitely was the problem.